# Spring Snake case conversion not working on foreign key column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have my entity definition like this:

```
@ManyToOne
private DomainObject domainObject;
```

I get this error while running the code:

```
2017-10-30 14:58:52,517  WARN rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: 127 - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2017-10-30 14:58:52,520 ERROR rnate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: 129 - Unknown column 'domainObject_id' in 'field list'
```

My table FK column is named `domain_object_id`.

I have this in my application.yml:

```
properties:
  hibernate:
    naming:
        strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
```

I was expecting it to generate the SQL as `domain_object_id`, but it is converting as `domainObject_id`. What am I doing wrong?

Other non Foreign Key columns are getting converted fine. The issue is only with Foreign Key columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try using javax.persistence.JoinColumn

```
@ManyToOne
JoinColumn(name="domain_object_id")
private DomainObject domainObject;
```

That way you are sure that the column will be named exactly as you want

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks. But I  am still curious how it worked in some other project without this annotation. Waiting to see if someone else can point me to the root cause of this problem....

Answer (score 0):

It is generating `domainObject_id` because of this attribute `private DomainObject domainObject;`

If you are expecting `domain_object_id` then use, `private DomainObject domain_object;`. Since the `_id` will be appended at the end of parameter name.

Comment: Nope. I think this should work without underscore in attribute name. I have other projects where the camel case conversion definitely worked.